# Associated bundles

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

Do two associated bundles (one the associated of the other) share same transition functions in general?
(If yes why? If no why?)

Can anyone give me a reference where I can find the rigorous definition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the associated bundle trans. functions just composing with the action you are considering. E.g. if the $G$-principal bundle has trans. fun $g_{\beta \alpha}:U_{\alpha}\cap U_\beta \to G$ and the action you are considering is $\rho:G\to \mathrm{Aut}(V)$ then the transition functions of the assiciated bundle are given by $\rho\circ g_{\beta \alpha}$.

The classic reference would be Kobayashi-Nomizu vol 1 but they don't play much with transition functions. You can find this perspective more used in Nicolaescu "Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds".

Comment: A transition function is defined to be a map $g_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\to G$. The composition with the action is not such kind of map. Moreover, the action on the fibers of the associated bundle should make the group $G$ act on the fiber through the transition functions. So what I would expect is some kind of $g'_{ij}$ which acts on elements of the fiber of the associated bundle via the action $\rho$.

Comment: Transition functions of the associated bundle will take value in group $Aut(V)$, so the structure group will be a subset of $Aut(V)$ (the image of $\rho$). If $\rho$ is injective (the action of $G$ on $V$ is effective) then indeed you will have a subgroup isomorphic to $G$, then as you want they will take values in $G$. 
In general the transition maps of the associated bundles will take values in a quotient of $G$. Think of the relations between $TM$ (tangent bundle) $\mathcal{F}M$ the frame bundle of $M$ which is a principal $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ bundle and the determinant bundle $\Lambda^nTM$

Comment: Use that $\Lambda^n TM = \mathcal{F}M\times_{\det}\mathbb{R}$

Comment: But also for the tangent bundle the structure group is $GL(n,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: My point is that the action should only take part in the game when I want to consider how the structure group (via transition functions) acts on the fibers. Thus $\rho\circ g_{ij}$ is precisely that!
I try to explain this better: I have one bundle $E\to M$ with fibers $F$ with action on these fibers $\rho$. I consider a space $\tilde F$ with effective action $\tilde\rho$. Given the transition functions $g_{ij}$ for $E$, I can build an associated bundle $\tilde E$ with fibers $\tilde F$ s.t. we have same transition functions, but the action is different, since it is given by $\tilde\rho$.

Comment: Is it only a problem of how we define transition functions and so forth?